# Maximum call stack size exceeded when filtering objects with inverse relationship ( Realm 10.1.1 )

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, realm, mongodb-realm

Giving the following schema:

```
const Person = {
  name: "User",
  primaryKey: "_id",
  properties: {
    _id: "objectId",
    name: "string",
    age: "number",
    company: "Company[]"
  }
};

const Company = {
  name: "Company",
  primaryKey: "_id",
  properties: {
    _id: "objectId",
    name: "string",
    boss: {
      type: 'linkingObjects',
      objectType: 'Person',
      property: 'company'
    }
  }
};
```

After adding some persons and several of them with a company, I try to filter by age and get the ones that are over 30 years with the code `realm.objects("Person").filtered("age > 30");`

The result of this query is the following error:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded.

I expect to have a list of Persons which meets the requirement, but instead I have this error. I have seen that in the release 10.0.0 this error is suppose to be fix for `toJSON()` function. If I try to filter the object by its id everything works fine, but once I try to get a list of some objects I get this error.

Does somebody have a solution for this?

**I´m using -->
Realm: 10.1.1
React Native: 0.62.2
Node: 10.22.1**

Comment: It's probably traversing the "company" link on each Person, which then has a link back to a list of Person objects, and so the infinite loop.

Comment: Yes , that´s what I thought but if I try to run realm.objects("Person").filtered("id === 1") where person with id = 1 has a company, this problem does not happen. I get the person with the reference to company with this "infinite loop". @Pointy

Comment: @Pointy I may be overlooking something but I don't think that's the issue. As is, that's how inverse relationships are constructed in Realm. See the docs [Inverse Relationships](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#inverse-relationships). The parent `Person` object has a list of companies `company: "Company[]"` and then each company has an inverse relationship back to the person `type: 'linkingObjects'`. I would prefer the var to be more appropriately named `companies` since it's a many-many but that's personal preference.

Comment: @Jay well I'm not sure either, but if there's an infinite recursion from that Mongo API that's the only cause I can think of. The data structure has a reflexive relationship.

Comment: @Pointy I wouldn't think that realm query would cause *that* error. I wonder if it's a react error...

Comment: @Jay well from the code posted, React should have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Pointy This may have something to do with it [React native - Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945849/react-native-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

Comment: @Jay possibly, but there's no React-specific code posted in the question.

Comment: Hello @Jay After further investigation on this topic I´v seen that this problem is only happening with Jest while executing test.